# Is $G$ a subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-groups

Let $G=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}$ exist in $GL(2,\mathbb R)$.

So in order to prove this is a subgroup we need to show $G$ is closed with respect to $*$ and we also need to show $G$ is closed with respect to taking inverses.

I know $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1/a&1/b\\0&1/d\end{bmatrix}$$ which exists in $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ since these are all real numbers.

Now to show it is closed under $*$ we will do $$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a^2&ab+bd\\0&d^2\end{bmatrix}.$$  Since this exists in $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ then it is closed under $*$.  [Thus $G$ is a subgroup].

I'm not sure if this is right but I just used the defintion of a subgroup.

Comment: Your formula for $A^{-1}$ is wrong. Also, for some real numbers $x$ there is no such thing as $\frac1x$

Comment: Also. it is unclear to me why you are looking at $AB\in G$ only for the special case $A=B$.

Comment: You’ve only shown that if $A\in G$ then $A*A\in G.$ (And the previous commenter is correct, your definition of $A^{-1}$ is wrong.)

Comment: My apolgizes the matrix is, /begin{bmatrix}1/a&-b/ad\\0&1/d\end{bmatrix}.  What would be another matrix I could use besides A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong about the inverse. It turns out that$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1a&-\frac b{ad}\\0&\frac1d\end{bmatrix}.$$But it is still an element of $G$ and therefore there is no problem here.

And in order to prove that $G$ is closed with respect to the product of matrices, you should take *two* elements of $G$:$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'\\0&d'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}aa'&ab'+bd'\\0&dd'\end{bmatrix}\in G.$$